# Wireguard how make access only to the local network for some clients on centos?

Tags: vpn, wireguard

I need some of the clients to have access to the internet when connected through the wireguard, and some only see the local network for access to samba, but without access to the Internet. I have `Centos` with standard settings that I took from the Internet

`wg0.conf`

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.8.0.1/24
PrivateKey = SERVER_PRIVATE_KEY
ListenPort = 35053

[Peer]
PublicKey = CLIENT_PUBLIC_KEY
AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.2/32
```

To get internet access for a client that connects to the wireguard, I do the following

```
vim /etc/sysctl.conf 
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
sysctl -p


firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=35053/udp
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-masquerade
firewall-cmd --reload
```

I add this on the client and everything works fine, I connect to the server and the client has the internet, it also has access to the server's local network and samba

`client.conf`

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = CLIENT+PRIVATE_KEY
Address = 10.8.0.2/24
DNS = 1.1.1.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = SERVER_IP:35053
PersistentKeepalive = 20
```

How can I add another client so that he has access to the local network and samba, but does not have access to the internet through masquerading?

I tried to add another wireguard interface `wg2` that would only work on the local network. This does not work, because the `public zone` already has masquerading and it is being applied to `wg2`. You can buy another external IP then it will work, but maybe there are some other solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/714015/537971

Basically, on server side you need to add your LAN CIDR to `AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.2/32` for example: `AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.2/32, 192.168.1.0/24`.

> I tried to add another wireguard interface wg2 that would only work on the local network. This does not work, because the public zone already has masquerading and it is being applied to wg2.

The second Wireguard instance should have different CIDR like `10.9.0.0/24` and the masquerade should be configured for one CIDR and Interface only, iptables example:
`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE` or `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -i wg0 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`
You should try mimic this behavior on firewalld or get rid of it on such setup with complex requirements.

Comment: Have you tried doing this in Rocky Linux 9?

Comment: No, but distribution matters less than we think it does. Here's a guide if you want to try using iptables/nftables: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-disable-firewalld-and-and-switch-to-iptables-in-centos-rhel-7/
I skimmed through firewalld docs and it seems to support less features than iptables.