# How to ping ISP router from external wireguard client via wireguard's server?

Tags: routing, wireguard

Given this setup:

```
2.2.2.2: name: client
         WireGuard address: 10.0.0.2
    ^
    |
<internet>
    |
    v
1.1.1.1: name: gw (ISP router)
         LAN address: 192.168.1.1
    ^
    |
    v
192.168.3.1: name: wg (br-lan)
             WireGuard server
             WireGuard address: 10.0.0.3 (wg0)
             WAN address: 192.168.1.3 (wan)
```

client (2.2.2.2) can ping all of wg's addresses (10.0.0.3, 192.168.3.1 and 192.168.1.3),
but it can't ping gw's lan address (192.168.1.1).

`ip route` shows:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wan src 192.168.1.3 metric 1024
10.0.0.0/24 dev wg0 scope link src 10.0.0.3
10.0.0.2 dev wg0 scope link
192.168.1.0/24 dev wan scope link metric 1024 
192.168.3.0/24 dev br-lan scope link src 192.168.3.1
```

Based on other answers, on wg (192.168.3.1) I tried

`ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 10.0.0.3 dev wg0`

and when that didn't work, I deleted the route, restarted the network, and tried

`ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.1.3 dev wan`

and when that didn't work, I deleted the route, restarted the network, and tried

`ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.1.1 dev wan`

but no luck. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

P.S. cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
shows "1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does your `AllowedIPs` in `wg.conf` look like?

It should look like this if you want to access both networks:

```
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32, 192.168.1.0/24
```

Then on WireGuard server apart from `ip_forward` you also need to set up Masquerade and forwarding between `wan` and `wg`:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wan -j MASQUERADE
```

so the firewall knows where to forward these packets.

Example:

```
10.10.4.10 - Wireguard Client -> <Internet> -> 10.10.4.1 - Wireguard Server ->
10.10.4.3 - RPI2 at Home acting as a Gateway for VPN -> Hosts in Local Network
```

I wanted to be able to ping my `192.168.1.1` (home router) from WireGuard, so here are steps needed:

On WireGuard server:

1. Change Allowed IPs for `10.10.4.3` (RPI) to:

   ```
   AllowedIPs = 10.10.4.3/32, 192.168.1.0/24
   ```
2. Add routing rule to access `192.168.1.0/24` via RPI:

   ```
   ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 10.10.4.3 dev wg0
   ```
3. Restart WireGuard:

   ```
   wg setconf wg0 /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf
   ```
4. Allow forwarding between networks

   ```
   iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.10.4.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -i wg0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 10.10.4.0/24 -i wg0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
   ```
5. Make sure that `ip_forward` is enabled:

   ```
   # cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
   1
   ```
6. Enable MASQUERADE

   ```
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.4.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
   ```

On Raspberry PI (VPN Gateway)

1. Enable `ip_forward`

   ```
   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
   ```
2. Enable MASQUERADE

   ```
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
   ```
3. Enable IP Forwarding between networks

   ```
   iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.10.4.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -i wg1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 10.10.4.0/24 -i eth0 -o wg1 -j ACCEPT
   ```

Results (on my PC):

```
$ ping -I wg1 -c 4 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) from 10.10.4.10 wg1: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=62 time=75.5 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=62 time=76.1 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=62 time=74.8 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=62 time=75.5 ms

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 74.802/75.475/76.082/0.454 ms

$ ping -c 4 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.251 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.204 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.211 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.210 ms

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3074ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.204/0.219/0.251/0.018 ms
```

My setup is a bit more complicated, so in your case you don't have to add routing rules on your WireGuard server but you definitely should make sure that:

1. Forwarding is allowed by Firewall Rules
2. MASQUERADE is enabled by Firewall Rules
3. Allowed IPs in your client config allow reaching your local network
4. Try pinging other hosts in the network from the WireGuard Client to eliminate the possibility of your router blocking pings from wg clients.

Comment: You were right! `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wan -j MASQUERADE` was all I needed. Since I'm running on OpenWRT, I had to first run `opkg update & opkg install iptables iptables-mod-nat-extra`. Thanks again for your detailed reply. It will certainly help others as well.

Comment: Which means your systems had all the pieces sorted out except address translation. Glad I could help!

Comment: On OpenWRT, it seems iptables has been deprecated, and replaced with nftables, so I migrated that command to the equivalent nft commands. It appears I could have installed `iptables-nft` instead of `iptables`, but chose the conversion route instead. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Ah yes, nftables is here to replace iptables, ip6tables and arptables.